# JavaFX and Gradle

Tags: java, intellij-idea, gradle, javafx

I'm new to using IntelliJ IDEA (and Java for that matter).

I want to create a project using JavaFX, but there are some dependencies that I need as well. I currently get these dependencies through Gradle. But when I set up a new JavaFX project in IntelliJ, it won't let me add Framework Support for Gradle (I guess Gradle isn't a Framework), but it would let me set up Framework support for Maven.

The opposite is true too. If I start a new Gradle Project, it won't allow me to add all of the boiler plate for JavaFX.

Is there anyway to configure a JavaFX and Gradle project in IntelliJ IDEA?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

My experience is more in Eclipse. But that being said, you can start a regular old Java project and still use JavaFX. So go ahead and use the Gradle project template.
Boilerplate with JavaFX shouldn't be an issue. It really doesn't have much. You can write a UI in it pretty concisely, and if you're just learning the language, it might be better to work from scratch anyway.

Comment: I feel a little ridiculous now. I thought there was a lot more boiler plate, but there isn't. It was mainly just two imports, adding an fxml file, and an extension to my class. Thanks!

Comment: Don't worry, everyone's posted questions and then facepalmed afterwards (myself included). Don't forget to accept the answer though if it resolved your issue.